# Function not executed when it is called

Tags: swift

I have the following basic code structure:

```
self.ok_today = 0
checkToday("Daily Steps")
if (self.ok_today == 0) {}
```

My problem is that the actions are not executed in order. When I run it, my variable is initialised to 0, then it executes the `if` block and after that the `checkToday()` method. (and since my variable is never incremented it always goes to the if block)

This the checkToday method, that uses Alamofire to fetch some data:

```
func checkToday(concept: String) {

        let user = "***"
        let password = "***"

        let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

       Alamofire
        .request(.GET, "http://***/ws/fhir/Observation?date="+self.todayStepsDate+"T00:00:00", headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            var json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            var i = 0
            while (json["entry"][i]["resource"]["valueQuantity"]["value"] != nil) {

                // Checks if the user synced his data for current day
                if (json["entry"][i]["resource"]["code"]["coding"][0]["display"].rawString() == concept){
                    let patientAux: String = "Patient/"+self.person_uuid
                    if (json["entry"][i]["resource"]["subject"]["reference"].rawString() == patientAux){
                        self.ok_today = self.ok_today+1
                    }
                }
                i=i+1
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea why I might have this problem?

Comment: Alamofire network requests are *asynchronous*. You could add a closure argument to the function to run after you get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alamofire requests are asynchronous. You should work with callbacks. Change your code to this to get the desired functionality.

```
func checkToday(concept: String, callback: () -> ()) {

        let user = "***"
        let password = "***"

        let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

       Alamofire
        .request(.GET, "http://***/ws/fhir/Observation?date="+self.todayStepsDate+"T00:00:00", headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            var json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            var i = 0
            while (json["entry"][i]["resource"]["valueQuantity"]["value"] != nil) {

                // Checks if the user synced his data for current day
                if (json["entry"][i]["resource"]["code"]["coding"][0]["display"].rawString() == concept){
                    let patientAux: String = "Patient/"+self.person_uuid
                    if (json["entry"][i]["resource"]["subject"]["reference"].rawString() == patientAux){
                        self.ok_today = self.ok_today+1
                    }
                }
                i=i+1
            }
            //code is done, now call the callback
            callback()
        }
    }
```

And use it like this

```
self.ok_today = 0
checkToday("Daily Steps") {
    //callback is called
    if (self.ok_today == 0) {}
}
```